# Using the OSX Cocoa-APIs from Mathematica via Link-Technology

Tags: mac-os-x, .netlink

I'd like to access Cocoa-API's (Foundation, AppKit) from *Mathematica* and have researched the following ways:

1. CocoaLink: A deprecated Package by Rob Schlofield from 2009, which is still available on GitHub but will not compile out of the box due to the introduced changes in the ObjC-Runtime made at that time and around 2010. I got it to work, but not for all Types. I contacted Rob if he will update CocoaLink but he told me that the effort would not justify the usefulness ... unfortunately.
2. MonoObjC: A Mono/.NET package which can be installed and used after Mono has been installed. Mono allows one to use .NETLink and invoke almost all .NET functions of the 4.0 Framework.

I have tried:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];

monobjc = LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc"];
foundation = LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc.Foundation"];
appkit = LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc.AppKit"];
```

Then I tried to load and instantiate a NSString but it failed with Messages telling me that the Bridge to ObjC is not available.

```
nsstring = LoadNETType["Monobjc.Foundation.NSString"];
sstr = NETNew[nsstring]
```

> NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Monobjc.Foundation.NSString ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Monobjc.ObjectiveCRuntime ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: monobjc_install_bridge
>   .....

I am not sure if there is more to be done to initialize .NETLink when working with other external mono packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I like to apologize for answering my own question because I overlooked some essential initial steps when working with MonObjC.

**Preconditions**

In order to access the Cocoa-APIs from Mathematica via *.NETLink* there need to be installed 2 separate packages:

- The Mono environment which can be obtained from here: [Mono Project Download Page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)
- The MonObjC Bridge (by Laurent Etiemble) here: [MonObjC Project Download Page](http://www.monobjc.net/downloads.html)

Both installers create symbolic links/commands which can be accessed from the terminal.

- `mono` for running .NET programs and others for several development tasks
- `monobjc` for running .NET programs which call Cocoa API's on the Mac via a "bridge"

It turns out that the `monobjc` command needs to be passed into the `MonoPath`option of `ReinstallNET`, after *.NETLink* has been loaded.

**Example**

To see if "something" can be called with `monobjc` from Mathematica I translated (or better: adapted) the [Console Application](http://www.monobjc.net/tutorial-console.html) from the tutorial section:

```
(* Load NETLink and make monobjc your link object *)
Needs["NETLink`"];
ReinstallNET["MonoPath" -> "monobjc"];

(* Mandatory load commands and initialization of the ObjC Runtime*)
LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc"];
LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc.Foundation"];
LoadNETAssembly["Monobjc.AppKit"];
LoadNETType["Monobjc.ObjectiveCRuntime"];

ObjectiveCRuntime`LoadFramework["Foundation"];
ObjectiveCRuntime`LoadFramework["AppKit"];
ObjectiveCRuntime`Initialize[];

(* Do what you like with Foundation and AppKit *)
LoadNETType["Monobjc.Foundation.FoundationFramework"];
LoadNETType["Monobjc.AppKit.NSScreen"];
LoadNETType["Monobjc.Foundation.NSDictionary"];

username = FoundationFramework`NSFullUserName[]@ToString[]
home = FoundationFramework`NSHomeDirectory[]@ToString[]
screen  = NSScreen`MainScreen@Frame@ToString[]
path = NETNew["Monobjc.Foundation.NSString",
    "/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/version.plist"];
dict = NSDictionary`DictionaryWithContentsOfFile@path;
version = dict@Description@ToString[]
```

The results on my MacBook

```
"Xacobeo"
"/Users/xacobeo2002"
"NSRect(NSPoint(0, 0) - NSSize(1280, 800))"
"{
    BuildVersion = 1;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = \"6.9\";
    CFBundleVersion = \"1265.21\";
    ProjectName = AppKit;
    SourceVersion = 1265021000000000;
}"
```

**Final remark**

Although the usage of Cocoa functions from Mathematica might be a bit verbose (there is no CocoaToExpression for automatic conversion of NSString, NSNumber, etc. to Mathematica types) it might be useful for somebody to occasionally call native APIs on the Mac. I always felt that on the Windows-Side you have things like `CreateCOMObject` in *.NETLink* which have no counterpart on the Mac and so there is at least a (compromised) workaround.

Comment: This is way too complicated than it should be.